# Binding Qt to LLVM

Tags: qt, binding, llvm

What is the best way to create a Qt binding to a language that sits on top of LLVM?

Try to parse the Qt header files and generate an interface to C from that, call the C interface from LLVM? Or maybe try to get SWIG to interface Qt? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at the [smoke libraries](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Languages/Smoke) from KDE? They wrap Qt as well.

Comment: Thank you. I cannot use them directly because they are GPL, but it is still useful to know their approach.